# How to return 2 property Values and string them together

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an element containing objects ,  i want to get all the values of 2 properties from the element example(data.number & data.name)

just for clarification  it holds the data in this format " 0 { number:30 , name : joseph } 1 { number: 340, name : micheal} "aplogies for confusion

and i want to string them together

example( value of data.number[0] & value of data.name[0] , value of data.number[1] & value of data.name[1] and so on ... )

here is what i have come up with so far:

```
 let finalarray = []
        for(let i=0; i<1; i ++){
          let nationNumber = Object.keys(myarraywiththedata).map(function(key){ return myarraywiththedata[key].number });
          finalarray.push(nationNumber)

         let nationName = Object.keys(myarraywiththedata).map(function(key){return myarraywiththedata[key].number });
          finalarray.push(nationName)
        }
```

but this doesn't work obviously

will accept edits to this post for readability

Comment: remember that `Object.entries(...)` exists. Or, if you didn't know that, [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) exists. Also remember to _either_ loop, _or_ iterate with an iteration function like `map`. Don't do both.

Comment: do you have some data and the result of it?

Comment: What is the purpose of your for-loop? Since `i=0; i<1` it only loops once. And you don't use `i` anywhere.

Comment: I would loop through `data` once, combine the name and number (into a string?), and push that into your `finalarray`.

Comment: apologies for the confusion it wasn't a true array i mistoke it for another element @Taplar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (assuming the properties in each object value are actually called "number" and "name").

```
let finalarray = Object.values(myarraywiththedata).map(({number, name}) => 
  `${number} & ${name}`
);
```